# Continuous X Dummy Variable interaction Interpretation

Tags: statistical-significance

I have an experiment where the same subjects perform a task under 3 conditions: saline (control), under drug A, and under drug B. The task has a parameter, "uncertainty", that ranges from 0 to 1, and makes the task easier or harder.

I want a linear model that explains the performance of the subject based on drug treatment, and uncertainty, and potential interactions. So far, I have:

Performance ~ a + b1 * drugA + b2 * drugB + b3 * uncertainty + b4 * drugA x uncertainty + b5 * drugB x uncertainty

The variables drugA and drugB are dummy variables, where:

if drugA = 0, drugB = 0, then session was saline (control)

if drugA = 1, drugB = 0, then session was under drug A

if drugA = 0, drugB = 1, then session was under drug B

OK. So I run the regression using statsmodel's OLS, and only the intercept 'a' and parameter 'b1' come out significant. The intercept not being 0 doesn't really mean much, so finally my question is about the interpretation of 'b1' being significant.

IF the interaction terms were not there, the interpretation to me is straightforward: the difference in performance between control and drugA is significant. Since the interaction term b4 was present, the interpretation changes. I *think* it means that the difference in performance between control and drugA, controlling for uncertainty, is significant.

1) is that interpretation correct ?
2) if that is true, why is the interaction not significant. Let's pretend the b4 (drugA x uncertainty) interaction is significant. What is the interpretation there ? Is it the difference in performance between control and drug A is greater when there is uncertainty (uncertainty > 0) than when there isn't (uncertainty = 0) ?

What is weird to me is that both b1 and b4 coming out significant seem to me to mean the same thing, and that can't be right. Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you include the term `b4` in your model, as long as the model determines that this term is not significantly different from 0, then you can consider that the term in your model *is* 0, for simplification. Hence your simplified model in your case would be:

```
Performance ~ a + b1 * drugA
```

And you interpret it as: the average performance for subjects when not taking `drugA` is `a` (which means this is the performance in the `saline` and `drugB` conditions), and the average performance for subjects when taking `drugA` is `a + b1`. To obtain this, simply replace `drugA` by 0 or 1, depending on the condition.

Now, if `b4` came out significant, then you would need to include the interaction effect in your model:

```
Performance ~ a + b1 * drugA + b4 * drugA x uncertainty
```

Now, using the same logic as before, we can replace `drugA` and `uncertainty` by real values depending on the conditions. When `drugA == 0`, so patient either have the saline solution or the drug B, then your model equates to

```
Performance ~ a + b1 * 0 + b4 * 0 x uncertainty
Performance ~ a
```

Now, when `drugA == 1`, we end up with

```
Performance ~ a + b1 * 1 + b4 * 1 x uncertainty
Performance ~ a + b1 + b4 * uncertainty
```

To further understand this, you would need to make `uncertainty` vary, but basically: when `uncertainty == 0` then you end up in the situation earlier, and you obtain the average score when participants take `drugA` and the task `uncertainty` is 0. When `uncertainty` is different from 0, then you start adding up a certain value `b4` proportionally to `uncertainty`.

If you want to say that in English, you would say that `drugA` has an impact on `Performance`, and that the uncertainty has an impact only under the `drugA` condition and no impact otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Arthur! I like the idea of treating the non-significantly different constants as, well, what they are: 0. What I still don't get, is that only b1 coming out significant translates to "the average performance for subjects when not taking drugA is a (which means this is the performance in the saline and drugB conditions), and the average performance for subjects when taking drugA is a + b1." Where does uncertainty come in ?

For example, if I run (Performance ~ a + b1 * drugA + b2 * drugB) only a is significantly different from 0. If I run (Perforamnce ~ a + b1 *drug A + b2 * drugB)

Comment: then both a *and* b1 come out significantly different than 0. So, adding uncertainty did change the result, and I think accounted for it somehow.

Comment: Both your formulae are the same so it's hard to tell what your point is... Just note that when I say "Performance is XXX" I'm really talking about an average estimated value from the model. Models try to fit the data as best as they could, given the parameters you put in them. So if you add more parameters, your model might tell you that the new parameters you added explain some of the variance in the data that was previously explained by another parameter, thus the significant effects won't be the same. A comment is a bit short to say much more than that, you should do some more reading.

Comment: the second formula is meant to be Performance ~ a + b1 * drugA + b2 * drugB + b3 * uncertainty. Yeah, my point is that adding uncertainty helped explained some of the variance, enough that now the model estimates that drugA *is* different to saline and drugB, where without it, it wasn't.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that one of your parameters was `uncertainty`, thought you were talking about model uncertainty. You also have to know that what effects will come up "significant" depends on how you determine significance. I don't know about other models but using `lmer` in R you can typically use any type of ANOVA to obtain significance values, depending on what you want to do. So that's another thing to consider. See the comments to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339859/171827) for example.